# Javascript Nested JSON Parsing

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json object that object contains main nodes and nested nodes. Each node have a property "type", i want to remove the nodes object which contains the property "type = doc".Please find below example json image format. I attached 2 files one image is the input format and other one is the output format.

```
var json =  {
"navigations": [
{
  "disp_order": "1",
  "menu_id": "25266",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "disp_order": "2",
      "menu_id": "18951",
      "type": "DOC"
    }
  ],
  "type": "MENU"
},
{
  "disp_order": "20",
  "menu_id": "25204",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "disp_order": "1",
      "menu_id": "10295",
      "type": "DOC"
    },
    {
      "disp_order": "10",
      "menu_id": "25207",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "disp_order": "999",
          "menu_id": "17250",
          "type": "DOC"
        },

      ],
      "type": "MENU"
    },
    {
      "disp_order": "20",
      "menu_id": "25209",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "disp_order": "999",
          "menu_id": "18881",
          "type": "DOC"
        },

      ],
      "type": "MENU"
    },
  ],
  "type": "MENU"
},

]
}
```

[image: Input Json Format]

[image: Output Json Format]

Comment: You should give it a try before posting a question

Comment: It would be easier for people to help you if you posted the actual JSON rather than images of the JSON. aka I ain't typing that out

Comment: But you clearly have the output format already, according to your second image, so there is a solution already. It it's some code, then you should ask if anything wrong with it. If you did it by hand, then just encode your thought process in javascript. Done.

Comment: No I just tried in a editor to show the output, i need the script.

Comment: Hint! Iterate over JSON and copy/remove wanted/unwanted node, simple as that.

Comment: Don't call a JavaScript object a JSON object. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/1hoctvdp/

```
function deleteNonMenu(obj) {
  if (obj.type == "DOC") {
    return true;
  }
  if (obj.nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.nodes.length; i++) {
      var res = deleteNonMenu(obj.nodes[i]);
      if (res == true) {
        delete obj.nodes[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < json.navigations.length; i++) {
  var result = deleteNonMenu(json.navigations[i]);
  if (result == true) {
    delete json.navigations[i];
  }
}
console.log(json);
```

Comment: This produces "gaps" (undefined) in the `nodes` arrays, ... See how in the fiddle you get a first `nodes` array of length 1, but with no elements. I don't think this is really desired.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, you could use this ES6 function, which leaves the original object immutable, and creates the filtered version as return value:

```js
function withoutDocNodes(obj) {
    return Object(obj) !== obj ? obj // Primitive value: return w/o change
        : Object.assign(Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {}, // Create array or object
            // With following properties:
            ...Object.keys(obj) // For each property:
                // Exclude those with DOC type in their value
                .filter( key => Object(obj[key]).type !== 'DOC')
                // Get recursive value (also without DOC types)
                .map( key => [withoutDocNodes(obj[key]), key] )
                // Exclude if resulting value is an empty (object or array)
                .filter ( ([o]) => Object.keys(o).length )
                // Produce key/value to add: arrays get index as property
                .map( ([o, key], i) => ({ [Array.isArray(obj) ? i : key]: o }) )
          );
}

const obj = {
  "navigations": [
    {
      "disp_order": "1",
      "menu_id": "25266",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "disp_order": "2",
          "menu_id": "18951",
          "type": "DOC"
        }
      ],
      "type": "MENU"
    },
    {
      "disp_order": "20",
      "menu_id": "25204",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "disp_order": "1",
          "menu_id": "10295",
          "type": "DOC"
        },
        {
          "disp_order": "10",
          "menu_id": "25207",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "disp_order": "999",
              "menu_id": "17250",
              "type": "DOC"
            },

          ],
          "type": "MENU"
        },
        {
          "disp_order": "20",
          "menu_id": "25209",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "disp_order": "999",
              "menu_id": "18881",
              "type": "DOC"
            },

          ],
          "type": "MENU"
        },
      ],
      "type": "MENU"
    },
  ]
};

const result = withoutDocNodes(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is also working, try this code :

```
function mainFunction() {
  var data = new Array();
  data = excludeDocs(json.navigations);
}

function excludeDocs(nodes) { 
    var _docs = new Array(); 
    $.each(nodes, function(index, node) { 
      if(typeof node === 'object') { 
          if(node.type === 'DOC') {
              _docs.push(node.menu_id); 
           } 
           else if(typeof node.nodes === 'object') { 
               var _nodes = excludeDocs(node.nodes); 
                if(!(typeof nodes === 'object' && nodes.length > 0)) { 
                     delete node.nodes; 
                } 
                else { 
                   node.nodes = _nodes; 
                } 
            } 
      } 
  }); 
  return nodes.filter(function(n) { 
      return !_docs.includes(n.menu_id); 
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful for data processing once you wrap your head around it.

Note: *(1)* Expects well behaved input and *(2)* modifies the input in place

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (type, input) => {
  objectScan(['**.nodes[*].type'], {
    filterFn: ({ value, gparent, gproperty }) => {
      if (value === type) {
        gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      }
    }
  })(input);
};

const json = { navigations: [{ disp_order: '1', menu_id: '25266', nodes: [{ disp_order: '2', menu_id: '18951', type: 'DOC' }], type: 'MENU' }, { disp_order: '20', menu_id: '25204', nodes: [{ disp_order: '1', menu_id: '10295', type: 'DOC' }, { disp_order: '10', menu_id: '25207', nodes: [{ disp_order: '999', menu_id: '17250', type: 'DOC' }], type: 'MENU' }, { disp_order: '20', menu_id: '25209', nodes: [{ disp_order: '999', menu_id: '18881', type: 'DOC' }], type: 'MENU' }], type: 'MENU' }] };

prune('DOC', json);
console.log(json);
// => { navigations: [ { disp_order: '1', menu_id: '25266', nodes: [], type: 'MENU' }, { disp_order: '20', menu_id: '25204', nodes: [ { disp_order: '10', menu_id: '25207', nodes: [], type: 'MENU' }, { disp_order: '20', menu_id: '25209', nodes: [], type: 'MENU' } ], type: 'MENU' } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)